# WinNMP (Nginx) returning "Directory access is forbidden."

Tags: nginx

I installed WinNMP with the typical install.
and added two files that I am using to check the installation(among others)

```
C:\Proj\MyRG\public_html\test.htm
C:\Proj\MyRG\public_html\application\index.htm
c:\winnmp\conf\nginx.conf file contains:
    root "C:/Proj/MyRG/public_html/application"
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\host file contains both these lines after the install:
    127.0.0.1 localhost
    127.0.0.1 ProjWinNMPTest.test #WinNMP ProjWinNMPTest.test #WinNMP public_html.test
```

Regardless of how I set WinNMP Manager-->Options(button)-->Projects Dir
when I read the test files from a browser

```
http://127.0.0.1/public_html/test.htm 
    correctly reads the simple htlm file.
http://127.0.0.1/public_html/application/index.html 
    returns "directory access is forbidden
'http://127.0.0.1/public_html/index.html 
    returns "404 file not found"
```

1) How can I set the root file for 127.0.0.1 to point to `C:/Proj/MyRG/public_html/application` instead of `C:/Proj/MyRG/public_html` ?

2) How can I get permission to access the directory ?

Comment: application/public_html is what you defined as root of the server, remove the public_html/application from your uris and it will work. I.e: `http://127.0.0.1/index.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem it is unrelated.  The index.html file itself was the 'directory access is forbidden